# code block inside rxjs subscription.add() will not be execute during jasmine test. Why?

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, angular-cli, code-coverage

Consider this method :

```
private subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription();

private addFoo(): void {
    this.subscriptions.add(this.fooService.createFoo(fooObj).subscribe(
      (foo: Foo) => {
        if (foo) {
          // do something
           this.isCreated = true; // coverage show that the test doest not go inside this.
        }
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error) {
          // error handling
        }
      }
    ));
  }
```

And the test case using jasmine:

```
 it('should create foo successfully', () => {
    spyOn(fooService, 'createFoo').and.returnValue(of(foo));
    component.addFoo();
    expect(component.isCreated).toBeTruthy()
  })
```

Running test with coverage show that the line `this.isCreated = true` will not be executed.. Does someone have an idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's an asynchronous operation? just try [fakeAsync](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync)

you should surround your test suit function in `fakeAsync` and call `flush` before the actual assertion

```
   it('should create foo successfully', fakeAsync(() => {
      spyOn(fooService, 'createFoo').and.returnValue(of(foo));
      component.addFoo();

      flush(); // pop async queue

      expect(component.isCreated).toBeTruthy()
    }))
```

Or alternatively, you can use [done](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async#callbacks) function from jasmine.  calling done be the last thing done by the asynchronous function or any of the functions that it calls

```
    it('should create foo successfully', function(done) {
      spyOn(fooService, 'createFoo').and.returnValue(of(foo));
      component.addFoo();

      expect(component.isCreated).toBeTruthy()
      done()
    });
```